# "A too large dataset is difficult to learn" vs "If the dataset is too large, the learning is difficult"

Tags: grammaticality, academic-writing

I am writing an academic paper. I wrote the sentence "A too large dataset is difficult to learn". My colleague told me she felt that it was not a complete sentence, and it is better to change it to "If the dataset is too large, the learning is difficult".
I also feel the original sentence seems to be incomplete but from the perspective of grammar, I cannot tell any problems.

Could anyone analyze why my original sentence seems to be incomplete?

Comment: "Too large a dataset is difficult to learn" is grammatical and idiomatic. "A dataset may be so large that it is difficult to learn" pre-empts debate over what 'too large' is intended to mean (it is probably redundant, "a dataset too large to learn easily is difficult to learn").

Comment: The biggest issue is that "too large dataset" is missing a determiner, since "dataset" is a count noun.

Comment: "An overly-large dataset" is one way to phrase this. I also agree with "Too large a dataset".

Comment: No agency in *difficult to learn*. For who? Students? A large book is not harder to read than a small one, page by page.

Comment: How do you learn a data set?  Are data sets taught?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grammar of "Too *adjective*" is a little odd.

You can use it as a predicate freely:

> This dataset is too large.

> Pianos are too heavy to lift.

But it is at least awkward to use it attributively:

> ? the too large dataset ...

> ? a too heavy piano ...

> ? too heavy pianos ...

Many English speakers will avoid expressions like this, and find a different way to say it (such as "a dataset which is too large").

There is a construction (which was referred to in a comment) where you can put "too xxx" **before** the determiner "a":

> too large a dataset

(only "a" is possible here - you can't use "the"). Edwin describes this "grammatical and idiomatic" in his comment: I would describe it as a bit formal.

Comment: You also see it with *of* like *too ADJ **of a** NOUN*, as in *[having] too large of a dataset*.

Comment: @tchrist: you do. I regard that as non-standard, and as a mis-perception of the unusual structure _too ADJ a NOUN_, but I may be out of date.